# mongoose schema / query

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to build out a friend component in my app.

I'm still fairly new to Mongo/Mongoose coming from a MySQL background.

What I'm trying to do here is access a user's profile and if their profile had a private setting to then check whether or not that user has the user that's accessing their page as a friend.

Suppose I have a User schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
username      : String,
friends       : [{ id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, status: Number }],
});

var User         = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

User.findOne({username: 'req.params.username', 'friends.id': req.session.user.id}, function (err, user)
if(user){
    user.isFriend = true;
}
});
```

I feel as though this only looks for any username with req.params.username OR any id with the req.session.user.id, rather than find a user with this username and see if req.session.user.id is in that user's friends' array.

is there a better way of doing this?

in MySQL it would be something like select from 'users' where username = 'something' and then checking that result to see if an id exists in the friends data of that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query always returns a document by `_id: username` if it exists. What you need to do is fetch the `friends` field and loop through it to see whether the `id` exists or not. Or a simple query using aggregate will also work.

```
    User.aggregate([{$match: {_id: req.params.username,
                              'friends.id': req.session.user.id}},
                    {$project: {friends: {$filter: {
                                                    input: '$friends',
                                                    as: 'fr', 
                                                    cond: {$eq: ['$$fr.id', req.session.user.id]}
                                                   }
                                         }
                               }
                    }
                   ]);
```

The above should return an array with one item and that one item has `friends` array in it, which in turn consists only one `id` if the given one exists in the `friends` list.

Note: `req.session.user.id` should be of type `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.